# Standard component size for antenna matching circuit

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching

I am fairly new to the RF world. It was certainly not my strongest subject. I am currently designing a board that uses the SIM868 module (GSM) and I need to design an antenna matching circuit. In the case above what size component should L1 be? 201, 402?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjQ74E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I know 0402 will work fine. So I recommend you use 0402. Same applies to C1 and C2. http://www.vishay.com/docs/60107/freqresp.pdf

Comment: There are higher Q 0402 inductors than 0201. The capacitors should be as small as possible (lower esl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what "Q" your PI matching circuit needs. And the surrounding components that parasitically-couple to the inductor. Are larger inductors more accurate/stable?